# Solving exact equation with partial derivatives and simplifying it to explicit form (issue with further simplification)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

> It holds that $$
> M(x, y) d x+N(x, y) d y=0
> $$ is in exact form if and only if
> $$
> \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}
> $$

$$
\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x+\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{4}\right) d y=0
$$
is exact if and only if

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{4}\right)\\
&\Leftrightarrow -12 x^{3} y^{2}=-12 x^{3} y^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Ok so I can prove that it is on exact form.

However I am unsure about how to solve it or whether I can get it simplified further. Can I only show it on implicit form? Also feel free to comment on my use of the if and iff arrows. I am not sure whether my notation is completely correct.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x+\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{4}\right) d y=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow \left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x=-\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{2}\right) d y\\
&\Rightarrow \int\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x=-\int\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{2}\right) d y\\
&\Rightarrow x^{5}-x^{4} y^{3}+c_{1}=-5 y+x^{4} y^{3}+c_{2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow 5 y-2\left(x^{4} y^{3}\right)=-x^{5}-c_{1}+c_{2}\\
&\Rightarrow y\left(-2 x^{4} y^{2}+5\right)=-x^{5}+c
\end{aligned}
$$

Also I am not completely sure why it is useful to determine whether a function is in exact form.

Comment: @Someone: where does the equation come from?

Comment: $$
\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x+\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{2}\right) d y=0
$$
is exact if and only if

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{2}\right)\\
&\Leftrightarrow -12 x^{3} y^{2}=-12 x^{3} y^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

I had a typo

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right) d x+\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{4}\right) d y=0$$
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(5 x^{4}-4 x^{3} y^{3}\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(5-3 x^{4} y^{4}\right)\\
 \implies-12 x^{3} y^{2}\color {red}{\ne}-12 x^{3} \color{red}{y^{4}}
$$
This is not exact.